# Как закрепить футер внизу страницы

Tags: html, css

Есть такая верстка:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
    Здесь header
    </div>

    <div id="content">
    здесь content
    </div>

    <div id="fotter">
    здесь fotter
    </div>

</div>
```

Допустим, у меня мало контента. И футер поднят вверх. Если я прописываю в css свойство

```
#content{
height:100%;
}
```

то если будет много контента, div контента не будет увеличиваться, а будет всегда height 100%.

Как выйти из такой ситуации, чтобы футер всегда был внизу вне зависимости от количества контента?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я не гуру в CSS, но попробую предположить, что можно прописать

```
#content{
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Если же нужен "прибитый" к нижней части экрана, то можно футеру задать `position:absolute;`

```
#footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Да и не забыть контенту дать нижний паддинг на высоту футера

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, то тебе нужен именно фиксированный подвал? Делается это достаточно просто:

```
#footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**html:**

```
<section>
  <article>CONTENT</article>
</section>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

**css:**

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;        
    text-align: center;
  }
section {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    background: #999;
  }
article {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
 }
footer {
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    background: #f00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4hv9y71o/

http://jsfiddle.net/w0y2mnj6/ - display: flex;

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю необходим прижатый к низу футер?
Вот пример такой разметки:

```css
html{
 height:100%;
}
body{
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
}
#content{
 width: 800px;
 min-height: 100%;
 background: #66ccff;
 margin:0 auto -150px;
}
#footer{
 width: 800px;
 height: 150px;
 background: #66cc00;
 margin:auto;
 clear:both;
}
.left{
 width:200px;
 float:left;
 outline:1px solid #9F00BF;
}
.right{
 width:200px;
 float:right;
 outline:1px solid #9F00BF;
}
.center{
 margin:0 210px;
 outline:1px solid #9F00BF;
}
.limiter{
 clear:both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Макет</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="content">
  <div class="right">text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br></div>
  <div class="left">text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text</div>
  <div class="center">text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br></div>
  <div class="limiter"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```